# Centering weird/misplaced for text in CSS

Tags: html, css, display

I am working on a project that has a part where I need text to be centered, but when I use `text-align:center;` this is what happens

[image]

Where the Hosting for school projects is off the line of being inline of Independent Study text.

Comment: +1 because I know that CSS centering is a pain.
However, I"d add a more comprehensive code example. Could you provide the actual HTML and CSS? The different Layers of CSS can matter. Which HTML attribute was it applied to? ETC.

Comment: The CSS to it is the body css which is
color: #fff;
    background-color: #23272a;
    font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `width` styles of both containers are equal in the example below.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.first {
  width: 400px;   /* the widht style of the first container is set to 400px. */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
}
.second {
  width: 400px;   /* the widht style of the second container is set to 400px. */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="first">
    <h1>Independent Study</h1>
  </div><br>

  <div class="second">
    <h3>Hosting for school projects</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```